# JavaFX - Make ScrollPane scroll automatically

Tags: java, user-interface, scroll, javafx, label

I have a Label inside a ScrollPane. I am updating the label in a loop (In another thread). How can I update the ScrollPane so it scrolls down (not sideways, this will be done manually) if the user doesnt hold it at a position? Is there a setter for it?

Comment: Could you explain this `if the user doesnt hold it at a position`?

Comment: If the user is not scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Math thanks , that worked!

```
@FXML private ScrollPane scroll; //this must match the fx:id of the ScrollPane element or be the scrollpane object
scroll.setVvalue(1.0);           //1.0 means 100% at the bottom
```

And I solved the problem "must be looking at the tab" with this part of code

```
tab.setOnSelectionChanged(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event arg0) {
        ScrollPane.setVvalue(1.0);
    }        
});
```

Comment: Actually there wasn't much information in your question saying what event should fire the scroll, so it was a kind of impossible to me to determine it by myself.

Comment: Thanks anyway. The whole problem is the tab , but I thought I should include what I did , in case someone finds it useful!

Answer (score 23):

To set the ScrollPane to the bottom automatically set the `vvalue` of the ScrollPane element, like this:

```
@FXML private ScrollPane scroll; //this must match the fx:id of the ScrollPane element
scroll.setVvalue(1.0);           //1.0 means 100% at the bottom
```

Comment: This is not working. (Offtopic : Why use FXML?(I use java and CSS sometimes)). Actually , it works only if I am at the tab.(If I have opened the specific tab)

Comment: The `FXML` file is where you build your Scene, then in the `Controller.java` you manipulate the elements associating a variable via the element's `fx:id`. If it is working only if you're in the tab it means you have to put the `.setVvalue()` somewhere else, depending on when you want to fire it, probably somewhere in the thread along with where you write in your Label.

Comment: I build my scene with pure java

Comment: Well.. you also have this option, but I discarded this since I knew about `SceneBuilder`. It works independently on your IDE and automatizes the process of building the `FXML` files. In my opinion, it worths to at least take a look at it.

Comment: OK. Got it . I have an idea. Since this thing works only if I am looking at the tab , I will add a listener (tab change/select event) and then set the vvalue. I came across different code snippets. None of them worked. I have a **TabPane**

Answer (score 8):

To scroll the scroll pane to the bottom completely, set its [`vvalue` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vvalueProperty--) to `1.0`:

```
scrollPane.setVvalue(1D);
```

Note this may not work when called after resizing the scroll pane's content.
In such a case, if delaying the call via `Platform.runLater()` doesn't fix the problem, consider setting the property's value in response to the content [`height` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#heightProperty--) invalidation event:

```
vBox.heightProperty().addListener(observable -> scrollPane.setVvalue(1D));
```

Answer (score 6):

This works in my code:

```
scrollPane.vvalueProperty().bind(mainGrid.heightProperty());
```

in my case scrollPane contains mainGrid

Answer (score 5):

If you are using either HBox or VBox within the ScrollPane, try the following:

```
hBox.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldvalue, Object newValue) {
        scrollPane.setHvalue((Double)newValue );  
    }
});
```

Comment: This only works by accident when the box's height is greater than or equal to `1.0`, that is the default maximum value of the `hvalue` property, which in turn should be `vvalue`. So an invalidation listener is sufficient. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037369/3453226) for a more correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
// adding a new row
vbox_event.addEventRow((Integer) null, null);
// scroll to bottom
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollpane.setVvalue(1.0);
    }
});
```