# javafx listview auto scroll to the end

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm using JavaFX ListView for the chatroom body of my Chat application. I add to the listview when a message comes or is being sent. This works well but I always have to scroll to find the latest message. Is there any way that I can auto scroll to the bottom so that the latest messages are displayed without having to scroll all the way down?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333396/javafx-make-scrollpane-scroll-automatically) and maybe [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156896/javafx-auto-scroll-down-scrollpane), too...

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. The thing is I'm not using a scroll pane. Im using only a ListView. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`ListView.scrollTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#scrollTo-int-) for this purpose:

```
public static <T> void addItem(ListView<T> listView, T item) {
    List<T> items = listView.getItems();
    int index = items.size();
    items.add(item);
    listView.scrollTo(index);
}
```

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to access the cell at a given index?

Comment: @SachiniWickramaratne Why do you want to do this? That is usually a bad idea (depending on what exactly "accessing the cell" means). Cells for certain indices may or may not be present at a given time and may come into view later. If this is about highlighting the new object(s) or something like this: This is possible but I cannot properly explain it in comments. I suggest asking a new question about this.

Comment: this is the purpose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765043/javafx-listview-update-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

`size` For example if only 10 items are visible set `size = 10;`

```java
private void autoScrollMessageList() {
    if (yourList.getItems().size() > size/*where size equals possible items to display*/) {
        yourList.scrollTo(yourList.getItems().size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addListener` on the list with a `ListChangeListener` to automatically update the list as items are added to it.

- This avoids intercepting calls to add items to the list (which can be challenging if using the `ObservableList` returned by `getItems()`).
- You can get the index of the updated item (with `change.getTo()`).

  - Incidentally, for a `change.wasAdded` event, `change.getFrom()` returns the list of added nodes too. See [the JavaFX `ListChangeListener.Change` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) for more.
- Additionally, I found that it was scrolling to the start of the newly added last element (i.e., to the second-last element) unless I wrapped my call to `scrollTo` with `Platform.runLater`.

```java
    public void initialize() {
        // Scroll to the bottom of the list as new items are added.
        messageList.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener<ChatMessage>) change -> {
            // Loop over the changes in the event.
            while (change.next()) {
                // If the change is that a ChatMessage was added, scroll to the index of that chat message.
                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> messageList.scrollTo(change.getTo()));
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I added this code to the `initialize` method of  my Controller.