# Javafx ListView update dynamically

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am creating a Chat application with JavaFx. My friend list is loaded into a ListView. My requirement is to show a notification icon when the user receives a message from a friend. For that I need to know the cell in which the friend is and also I need to show the notification icon. I cannot figure out a way to do this as I;m very new to FX. 
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
Thank you

Comment: Use cell rendering. You can show a scene(FXML) as a list cell value.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you point me to a good example? I'm kinda lost here

Comment: Sure ...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the info about the friends you are notified about in some observable. This could be the item class itself

```
public class Friend {

    private final IntegerProperty messageCount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public int getMessageCount() {
        return messageCount.get();
    }

    public void setMessageCount(int value) {
        messageCount.set(value);
    }

    public IntegerProperty messageCountProperty() {
        return messageCount;
    }

    ...

}
```

or an external data structure like `ObservableMap` as used in the following example:

```
public class Friend {

    private final String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // map storing the message counts by friend
    final ObservableMap<Friend, Integer> messageCount = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    ListView<Friend> friendsListView = new ListView<>();
    friendsListView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Friend>() {
        final StackPane messageNotification;
        final Text numberText;
        final InvalidationListener listener;

        {
            // notification item (white number on red circle)
            Circle background = new Circle(10, Color.RED);

            numberText = new Text();
            numberText.setFill(Color.WHITE);

            messageNotification = new StackPane(background, numberText);
            messageNotification.setVisible(false);

            listener = o -> updateMessageCount();
            setGraphic(messageNotification);
        }

        void updateMessageCount() {
            updateMessageCount(messageCount.getOrDefault(getItem(), 0));
        }

        void updateMessageCount(int count) {
            boolean messagesPresent = count > 0;
            if (messagesPresent) {
                numberText.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            }
            messageNotification.setVisible(messagesPresent);

        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Friend item, boolean empty) {
            boolean wasEmpty = isEmpty();
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (wasEmpty != empty) {
                if (empty) {
                    messageCount.removeListener(listener);
                } else {
                    messageCount.addListener(listener);
                }
            }

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("");
                updateMessageCount(0);
            } else {
                setText(item.getName());
                updateMessageCount();
            }

        }

    });

    Random random = new Random();
    List<Friend> friends = Stream
            .of(
                    "Sheldon",
                    "Amy",
                    "Howard",
                    "Bernadette",
                    "Lennard",
                    "Penny")
            .map(Friend::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

    friendsListView.getItems().addAll(friends);

    List<Friend> messages = new ArrayList(friends.size() * 2);

    // 2 messages for each friend in random order
    Collections.shuffle(friends, random);
    messages.addAll(friends);
    Collections.shuffle(friends, random);
    messages.addAll(friends);

    // demonstrate adding/removing messages via timelines
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        Iterator<Friend> iterator = messages.iterator();

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            messageCount.merge(iterator.next(), 1, Integer::sum);
        }

    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(messages.size());

    Timeline removeTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        Iterator<Friend> iterator = messages.iterator();

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            messageCount.merge(iterator.next(), 1, (a, b) -> a - b);
        }

    }));
    removeTimeline.setCycleCount(messages.size());

    new SequentialTransition(timeline, removeTimeline).play();

    Scene scene = new Scene(friendsListView);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

For message counts stored in the `Friend` class you'd need to modify registering the listener and updating the cell a bit.

```
listener = o -> updateMessageCount(getItem().getMessageCount());
```

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Friend item, boolean empty) {
    Friend oldItem = getItem();
    if (oldItem != null) {
        oldItem.messageCountProperty().removeListener(listener);
    }

    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText("");
        updateMessageCount(0);
    } else {
        setText(item.getName());
        item.messageCountProperty().addListener(listener);
        updateMessageCount(item.getMessageCount());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks heaps. I tried doing it this way but since I already have a graphic set for the display picture of the friend, I'm confused about it. How do I tackle both graphics? I edited my question with the image

Comment: Hi again.. can u explain boolean wasEmpty = isEmpty();
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (wasEmpty != empty) {
                if (empty) {
                    messageCount.removeListener(listener);
                } else {
                    messageCount.addListener(listener);
                }
            }

Comment: If the cell was changed from empty to non-empty or the other way round, add or remove the listener depending on the state of the empty property after the update. (You don't need updates for empty cells since they always remain empty regardless of the state of the map)